# Spring Configuration to be Global

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I am building rest services , in which it consumes Soap service. In my `Util` Class I have a method to connect to the endpoint something like that

```
@Configuration
@PropertySporce("classpath:application.properties")
public Class Util(){

    public Weather getWeatherService(){
    WeatherService_Service  =  new WeatherService_Service(wsdlURL, new QNAME("urn value",Weather)
    endpoint  =  service.getBasicHttpBindingWeather;
    return endpoint
}
```

In my service layer I do

```
@Autowired 
Utils util
```

and for each method listed in service layer I have to first get the endpoint and then use the soap operation something like below

```
Weather weather =  util.getWeatherService();
weather.getWeatherByCity(Zipcode)
```

Is there a way I can make it a global so that It is only called once while the application is initialized , so that my soap calls to the system are minimized.

Comment: `so that It is only called once` what is? The `getWeatherService()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your configuration..

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public Class Util(){

    @Bean
    public Weather weatherService(){
        WeatherService_Service  =  new WeatherService_Service(wsdlURL, new QNAME("urn value",Weather)
        endpoint  =  service.getBasicHttpBindingWeather;
        return endpoint
    }
}
```

Now your endpoint is a bean like all others and you can simply inject it instead of the configuration class.

```
@Autowired 
Weather weatherService;
```

Comment: Already tries this , does not work as when I do weatherService., I see there are no soap Operations available for me

Comment: How do I import the Weather Bean in my other class

Comment: You don't import the class. It is a configuration class which will be loaded by spring which should also load and configure your service. If that isn't the case you either aren't using Spring or are using your classes in the wrong way.